# Проверка корректности введенных данных

Tags: c++

Я думаю я разобью проблему на два вопроса, так как они большие.
Собственно есть задача. Описать клас Процессор который содержит информацию про марку,частоту, кеш и стоимость. Предусмотреть инициализаию с проверкой коректности данных.

Как собственно сделать так чтоб при вводе не числа в поля

```
`float chastota;
float cash;  float vartist;`
```

выводило сообщение что, мол ошибка, и програма останавливалась.

**Вот функция проверки** :

```
int perevirka()
  {
    if (isdigit(chastota)==false) 
    {
      cout<<"\nvvedeno bukvu zamist zifri v strichzi chastota"<<endl;
      return 0;
    }
    if (isdigit(cash)==false)
    {
      cout<<"\nvvedeno bukvu zamist zifri v strichzi cash"<<endl;
      return 0;
    }
    if (isdigit(vartist)==false)
    {
      cout<<"\nvvedeno bukvu zamist zifri  v strichzi vartist"<<endl;
      return 0;
    }

  }
```

Результат компиляции: [Ссылка на repl.it](https://repl.it/KixK/5)

```
vvedit dani
Input brand:  intel
Input chastotu :  67
Input number of cash: p
Input vartist:Input brand: Input chastotu : Input number of cash:Input vartist:
vvedeno bukvu vmesto zifri v stroke chastota

vvedeno bukvu vmesto zifri v stroke chastota
intel   67  0   0
    0   0   0
```

**Вот весь код.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;


class Prozessor
{
  private:
  char marka[20];
  float chastota;  
  float cash;
  float vartist;

  public:

  void setProzessor()
    {
        cout << "Input brand: ";
        cin >> marka;
        cout << "Input chastotu : ";
        cin >> chastota;
        cout<<"Input number of cash:";
        cin>>cash;
        cout<<"Input vartist:";
        cin>>vartist;
    }
  void showProzessor()
  {
    cout << marka << " "<<'\t' << chastota <<" "<<'\t'<< cash << " " <<'\t'<< vartist <<endl;

  }
  int perevirka()
  {
    if (isdigit(chastota)==false) 
    {
      cout<<"\nvvedeno bukvu vmesto zifri v stroke chastota"<<endl;
      return 0;
    }
    if (isdigit(cash)==false)
    {
      cout<<"\nvvedeno bukvu vmesto zifri v stroke cash"<<endl;
      return 0;
    }
    if (isdigit(vartist)==false)
    {
      cout<<"\nvvedeno bukvu vmesto zifri  v stroke vartist"<<endl;
      return 0;
    }

  }
};

int main()
{
   Prozessor Obj1;
   Prozessor Obj2;
   cout<<"vvedit dani"<<endl;
   Obj1.setProzessor();
   Obj2.setProzessor();

   Obj1.perevirka();
   Obj2.perevirka();

   Obj1.showProzessor();
   Obj2.showProzessor();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://repl.it/KixK/16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понимаю, вы хотите что-то вроде этого?

```
void input(const char * prompt, double& var)
{
    for (;;) {
        std::cout << prompt << std::flush;
        if ((std::cin >> var).good()) return;
        if (std::cin.fail()) {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cout << "Неверный ввод, повторите.\n";
        }
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max(), '\n');
    }
}

int main()
{
    double x;
    input("Введите x: ",x);
    cout << x << endl;
}
```

Comment: +1 за (std::cin >> var).good(). Не думал что такое вообще есть...

Comment: да, чтото вроде етого. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам нужно

```
_DEBUG_ERROR("error text");
```